# PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered need fix

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

I got this error when doing action to create order
PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /home/elazbagr/mysite/wp-content/plugins/custom-point/custom_point.php on line 257

where line 257 is

```
            $diff = $duration - $stored_date;
```

and this lines up and down

```
            $duration = get_option("wc_settings_tab_period_of_changes",true);
            //$today_date = date("Y/m/d");
            $diff = $duration - $stored_date;
            //$diff = abs(round($diff / 86400));
            if($duration == 0) {
```

please help me to fix this
regards

Comment: What is in the various variables? Are they just numbers, or are they formatted dates?

Comment: field to ad numbers of days

Comment: If one is a formatted date and the other is a number of days, you can't just add them together like this. There are plenty of functions for manipulating dates, though. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what value has variable $stored_date,

as php says `A non-numeric value`

try smth like this:

```
$diff = (int)$duration - (int)$stored_date;
```